# Народ, помогите с кодом. после правке в цикле while подсвечивает summ как ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сидел себе делал цикл while, как только он начал работать код начал выдавать ошибку в `summ()`,там где ее раньше не было.

```
def multp():
    a=int(input('введите первый множитель: '))
    b=int(input('введите второй множитель: '))
    print('{}*{}={}'.format(a, b, a * b))
def summ():
    a=int(input('введите первое слагаемое: '))
    b=int(input('введите второе слагаемое: '))
    print('{}+{}={}'.format(a, b, a+b))
def subt():
    a=int(input('введите уменьшаемое: '))
    b=int(input('введите вычитаемое: '))
    print('{}-{}={}'.format(a, b, a-b))
def div():
    a=int(input('введите делимое: '))
    b=int(input('введите делитель: '))
    print('{}/{}={}'.format(a, b, a/b))
def ChooseAction():
    choice=0
    while choice not in {1, 2, 3, 4}:
        print('''Напишите только цифру действия.
        1-сложение
        2-вычитание
        3-деление
        4-умножение ''')
        choice=int(input())
    return choice
def Action(ChooseAction):
    if ChooseAction == 1:
    summ()
    elif ChooseAction == 3:
    div()
    elif ChooseAction == 2:
    subt()
    elif ChooseAction == 4:
    multp()
ActionNumber=ChooseAction()
Action(ActionNumber)
```

Comment: И какая ошибка?

Comment: У меня Ваш код исправно работает. Добавьте табуляцию после операторов 'if' в функции 'Action' и никакой ошибки не будет.

Comment: синтаксис? после if ChooseAction == 1: нет отступов перед summ()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

предположу, что ошибка выдается на это

```
def Action(ChooseAction):
    if ChooseAction == 1:
    summ()
    elif ChooseAction == 3:
    div()
    elif ChooseAction == 2:
    subt()
    elif ChooseAction == 4:
    multp()
```

надо

```
def Action(ChooseAction):
    if ChooseAction == 1:
        summ()
    elif ChooseAction == 3:
        div()
    elif ChooseAction == 2:
        subt()
    elif ChooseAction == 4:
        multp()
```

когда я исправил - программа стала работать

**P.S.**

вместо

```
print('{}*{}={}'.format(a, b, a * b))
```

лучше используйте f-строки, это нагляднее и удобнее

```
print(f'{a}*{b}={a * b}')
```

Comment: Боже так накосячить на пустом месте(facepalm)
За способ спасибо )

Comment: @Максрябов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers